# Found in Africa

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking

The answer to this puzzle is a six-letter word.

---

> One thousand one.
> [image]
> "One friend"
> [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> **[IMPALA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impala)** - an antelope found in eastern and southern Africa.

To find this:

> Write '*One thousand one*' in Roman numerals as 'MI', but read these letters from right to left, as suggested by the left-pointing arrow. This gives us '**IM**'.
>
>  Next, interpret '*One friend*' as A PAL, but swap these two words around, as suggested by the pair of arrows pointing in opposite directions. This gives us **PALA**.
>
>  Together, IM + PALA gives us **IMPALA**!

Comment: Correct. Well done!